# Blur on axis X only

Tags: jquery, css, blur

Hello is it possible to make blur effect only by axis X with Jquery or CSS3?

I found CSS3 filter and .blur in jquery, but it make blur on X and Y. And I need only X.

Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

[`blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#blur%28%29) does not have any directional controls, as it's a gaussian blur and that is omnidirectional.

If you're looking to have a box fade out around certain edges, you might want to look at using [`box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) instead.